# Full calendar show event length during resize

Tags: fullcalendar

Im using Adam Shaw's FullCalendar (http://fullcalendar.io).

I'm looking for a way to show a tooltip at the mouse pointer when a user resizes an event in the calendar. I'd like it to show the actual event length, and should be updated as the user drags.

When looking in the documentation i can't seem to find any method for this.

Has someone any suggestions for this?

Thanks, Simon

Answer (score 0):

You can use [qtip plugin](http://qtip1.com//) and then use it like in the [documentation example for event render](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/)

In addition, to get the length you can do it with [moment.js difference method](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) as you can check in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/u90Kal?p=preview).

So finally you got something like:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.qtip({
            content: event.end.diff(event.start, 'minutes')
        });
    }
```

Comment: Neat! it didn't quite work as planned with qTip, you have to drag pretty slow for qTip to catch up updating the tooltip. And there seems to be a problem when shrinking an event, i got a lot of duplicate tooltips as i draged. 
My biggest concern is if there's a solution for when users are creating new events?